# Is it possible to ice fish during winter?

Tags: the-infected

I've just transitioned to winter, and the fish ponds are frozen over.  I've tried striking the ice with my pick and axe to form a hole for ice fishing, but am unable to break the ice.  Are there other methods for ice fishing during winter, or must we rely on hunting animals for protein sources?